# Performing unsupervised k means classification in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, classification, image

I'm running QGIS 2.16 on Windows 10.

I'm looking to perform an unsupervised K means classification on a geoTiff image I have from a multispectral camera surveying sugar cane fields.

Alas, the [documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/learning/unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification.html) for the algorithm in QGIS needs work done to make the code user friendly to use in the Python console.

Parameters
Input Image [raster]

Available RAM (Mb) [number] Default: 128

Validity Mask [raster] Optional.  ## I don't know what this means.

Training set size [number] Default: 100  ## Or this

Number of classes [number]

Default: 5

Maximum number of iterations [number]Default: 1000 ##Don't know either

Convergence threshold [number] Default: 0.0001

OUTPUTS:

Output Image [raster]   ## I imagine it's the layer with the classification done
Centroid filename [file]   (Not exactly sure, I know what centroids are but                     ##those work for polygons in vector files not raster files).

I'm thinking maybe it's because I don't have the OrfeoToolbox installed but I´m positive I do because I downloaded and installed QGIS 2.16 along with GRASS and the OsGeo4w packages.